# Can I use recursion to handle GPIO?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, gpio

I'm newbie using STM32f100RB which is based on ARM Cortex M3.I was trying to use recursion to handle GPIO input, but it didn't work.Can anyone tell me why?
Codes are as following .
it's supposed to set the GPIOc Pin 9, when GPIOa Pin 0 is 1.But it just doesn't work..

I'm not sure if I can post a question like this.If it's not proper,let me know.Thank you.

```
    void detect_input(void);

    void main()
    {
        init_ports();
        detect_input();
        while(1)
        {
            GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_9, Bit_SET);//turn on the green led
        }
    }

    void detect_input()
    {
        if(!GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_0))
        {
        detect_input();
        }
   }
```

Comment: It's probably a bad idea, since embedded systems don't have much stack and you can easily cause a stack overflow with code like that.

Comment: Thank you! @Joachim Pileborg It must be the reason.

Comment: Embedded or not, your code will recurse itself into *infinity* if there is no input, so it is basically a very bad idea. I'd look at using an interrupt pin, then the code doesn't have to do *anything* until some input happens, it can spend its entire time doing other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your code, you probably will get a **stackoverflow**.

As I can see, in your code, if there is no input, so you will call the function `detect_input()`, and there is no other stopping condition. So, dependently on the frequency used and stack size, you will use all stack memory allowed.

Thus, that is not a good idea in general.

For this simple case, you should use the simple while loop:

```
void detect_input() {
    while(!GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_0));
}
```

In this case you will exit the looping at the moment that input will be received.